# Select a region over an arc

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, event-handling, geometry

I am trying to make a selection by clicking over an arc and drag around. The example below shows a very similar concept but the selection is starting from a random position, instead i would want  to start from a position on the dark blue arc by clicking the mouse over it and dragging around. 
http://jsfiddle.net/bno009s5/

```js
var dataset = {
  apples: [532, 284],
};

var degree = Math.PI / 180;

var width = 460,
  height = 300,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var pie = d3.layout.pie().startAngle(-90 * degree).endAngle(90 * degree)
  .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(50)
  .outerRadius(100);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(pie(dataset.apples))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .each(function(d) {
    this._current = d;
  }); // store the initial values;


window.setInterval(dummyData, 2000);

// Store the displayed angles in _current.
// Then, interpolate from _current to the new angles.
// During the transition, _current is updated in-place by d3.interpolate.
function arcTween(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}

function dummyData() {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  var key = Math.floor(Math.random() * dataset.apples.length);

  dataset.apples[key] = num;

  draw();
};

function draw() {
  svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(pie(dataset.apples))
    .transition()
    .attrTween("d", arcTween);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.4/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alkhoo/JwkYm/29/), with blue line visible. You can click inside and outside the circle, also try clicking below both endpoints.

The green circle is just for esthetics (ie: replace it with a favourite pet picture :-)
Tested to work in IE9, latest Chrome and FF (Oct 2014).

**Edit**: Added drag function. The code below is the original fiddle.

```js
var s = Snap(400,400);
var circleX = 100, circleY = 100, circleRadius = 57; 
var stroke_width = 20;
var blueCircle = s.circle(circleX, circleY, circleRadius);
var hcp = Math.Pi*circleRadius; // half circle perimeter = 179.0

//Arc Path
var d='M 43,100 A 57,57 0 0 1 43,100';
var arcPath = s.path(d);
arcPath.attr({
    fill: "none",
    stroke: "red",
    "stroke-width": stroke_width
});

// Line Path
var L1 = s.path("M "+circleX+" "+circleY +"L 0 0");
blueCircle.attr({
    fill: "none",
    stroke: "skyblue",
    "stroke-width": stroke_width,
    "stroke-dasharray": "0,179,179"
});
var c1 = s.circle(0,0,5).attr({ fill: "none",stroke: "green" });

function OnMouseDown(evt) {
    var mouseY = Math.min(evt.clientY,100); // limit mouseY to 100
   
    L1.attr({ d: "M "+circleX+" "+circleY +"L "+evt.clientX+" "+mouseY });
    var totalLength = L1.getTotalLength();
    if (totalLength < circleRadius) { // smaller, extend line
        var ratio = circleRadius/totalLength;
        var x_len = evt.clientX + (evt.clientX - circleX)*ratio;
        var y_len = mouseY + (mouseY - circleY)*ratio;
        L1.attr({ d: "M "+circleX+" "+circleY +"L "+x_len+" "+y_len });
    } 
    var PAL = L1.getPointAtLength(circleRadius);
    c1.attr({ cx: PAL.x , cy: PAL.y });
    draw_arc(PAL.x,PAL.y);
}

function draw_arc(endX,endY) { // Draw SVG arc
    // point starts on left at 43,100, 
    // Arc Box height is 57,57 (radius)
    // Ends at (endX,endY)
   
    var newArc ='M 43,100 A 57,57 0 0 1 '+endX+','+endY;
    arcPath.attr({ 'd': newArc });
}
document.onmousedown = OnMouseDown;
```

```html
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Hi Alvin, Below is the code that i had used   arcs.on("mousedown", function(d){ 
        var div= d3.select(this).classed("active",true) ; 
        currentSelected = this;
        console.log(d3.mouse(arcs.node()));
        d3.select(window)
        .on('mousemove', mouseMove)
        .on('mouseup', mouseUp);
        var point = d3.mouse(arcs.node());
         startAngle= (Math.atan2(point[1], point[0]) + Math.PI / 2);       
         console.log(startAngle);
         
              });  I have convert the x,y angle and i do same on mousemove event calc the end angle. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user3202499: Do you have a link to the fiddle for this coding?